# Select Only Direct Child Of Table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table which has another table inside it I need to style the main table but leave inner one as is. I tried to you the > selector in CSS however while styling the main table inner inherits everything the main has.

HTML

```
<table id="main-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="inner-table">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td >data</td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#main-table > tbody tr td{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #E6F4FF;
    color: #035B9C;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #E6F4FF;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify using > for all? :)

Comment: Duh, I made a mistake in implementation after giving the correct comment :P The version provided in dippas' answer is what I meant by `>` for all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, using direct children `>` for each one.

```css
#main-table > tbody > tr > td {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #E6F4FF;
  color: #035B9C;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #E6F4FF;
}

/* demo purposes */
td {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table id="main-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>data</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need! Thanks! :)

Comment: now also the inner table inherits from main table na?

Comment: @AnoopLL: I believe the question was not about stopping the *inheritance*. It was about making the rule not apply to the inner table's `td`. With the original code, the child table's `td` would have also got the `padding`, `border` etc (just revert the selector to the original and see how the height of second `tr` increases). With the modified one, that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

correction:

```css
#main-table > tbody > tr > td{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #E6F4FF;
    color: #035B9C;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #E6F4FF;
}
```

Comment: Worked with adding one more after tr :) Thanks !

Comment: This is not enough, it will still select `<td>` elements which are part of the inner table which is part of the `<tr>` of the outer table.